# Try to call add contact salesforce API. it's show session expired error

Tags: oauth2, php

I integrated salesforce one of my project for store user contact in Salesforce.

first, i was authenticate using below API link:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/success&state=mystate
```

it successfully redirects callback URL and given access_token. show below success page url.

```
https://www.example.com/success#access_token=xxxxxxx&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fap5.salesforce.com&id=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00D7F000004981JUAQ%2F0057F000001zY4ZQAU&issued_at=1514990502115&signature=ctEUOf7n%2BY9hKCTywHOXDpWURcu6tlokdfEBtqCDIZs%3D&state=mystate&scope=id+api+web+full+visualforce+openid&token_type=Bearer
```

at this step perfectly working. but using this access_token call add contact api it's always show **session expired error**.

Call Contact API code :

```
    $headers = array(
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer token',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            );

            // set url
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
//        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{'name':'sujal'}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization' => ' Bearer 00D7F000004981J%21ARQAQFZvTg0hvzPNDGP9cLFhIzHVUkTPOpJpfY9F6rO8imeK7ogMyiniPL.A_CRSenZ0Vi0IwN0zJWf6aItZAylGPdKkG57R', 'Acccept' => 'application/json', 'Content-length' => 100));

        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);


            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($output);
            exit;
```

Above code Response:

```
[
   {
      message: "Session expired or invalid",
      errorCode: "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
   }
]
```

What's wrong in above code?

Answer (score 2):

The `instance_url` in the callback shows that your org is on `ap5.salesforce.com`, but you're trying to use the session id on `na3.salesforce.com`.

It's unclear from your code whether you are actually sending the token in the Authorization header.  Are you extracting `access_token` from the hash and setting `$headers` such that `$headers['Authorization']` is set to `Bearer 00Dxxxxxxxxxxxx!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`?

There are a few other potentials problems with your code.  You're setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, but you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to an array, which should be used with `multipart/form-data`.  You also set `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `GET`, but you want to perform a `POST`.  You probably want to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to a json string, and not use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`.

Comment: Hey xn, thank for reply. i'm trying to change na3 to ap5 but it's same error.

Comment: You have an extra space before "Bearer".  You don't need to set the Accept header.  Content-Length should be the actual length of the json string.

Answer (score 0):

don't hard code the URL.
try to get it from the login response only. 
your instance url will vary from org to org.

even if you use the REST login API of salesforce it will return the org instance url along with access_token and you can use that only.

Comment: Hey sagar, i was try but same error [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]. same instance_url and api url at this time.

Comment: than something is missing or wrong. you can try on postman or anything other REST API explorer. if it runs successfully than try in your code

Comment: try passing Content-Length also along with your request.

Comment: in code I dont see any issue. if you have your salesforce org credentials than try doing it in [link]https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php
for me it is showing that your json in wrong. may be you can try

Comment: i'm trying your given api and it's show me. API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71219/discussion-between-sujal-patel-and-sagar).